# Unable to declare AOS library in functions

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, 404-error, library

Greeting WP Devs,

I am planning to transfer the script libraries in my function.php .
In my function.php I registered AOS

```
function mypage() {
  if ( is_page( 'mypage' ) ) {

wp_register_script( 'aosjs', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/aos.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );    
   wp_enqueue_script( 'aosjs' );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.min' );


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'testingarea');
```

Page Name : **mypage**

https://mysite/**mypage/**  - My script has **cdn**  with **AOS.init**

```
 <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
  AOS.init({
    easing: 'ease-in-out-sine'
  });
</script>
```

***First Test-*** AOS is registered in functions.php aand in mypage I removed the cdn in the mypage Page and aos init is still there but the result is

[image]

..

PLease kindly give me suggestions on how to declare this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the path without trailing slash.  
So you need to write

```
wp_register_script( 'aosjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/aos.js',...)
```

Note the slash before "js/aos.js".

What good for is this line, the script file should already be loaded:

```
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
```